# How to write if statements with || (OR) with less repetition?

Tags: javascript

I’m trying to write something that checks that letters are not equal to vowels. I know I can do this with regular expressions, but for the sake of learning more about conditional statements, how could I write something like this more efficiently?

```
if (myArray[i] !== "a" || myArray[i] !=="e" || myArray[i] !=="i" || myArray[i] !=="o" || myArray[i] !=="u") {
    console.log(myArray[i] + "");
}
```

By more efficient I mean more DRY without the `myArray[i] !== "a"` being repeated so much.

Comment: Well first thing to do is use `&&` instead of `||`, because the logic as written doesn't make sense.

Comment: `switch` would be a better choice

Comment: note that `||` doesn't shortcircuit: if it fails, the next might succeed, so you will always run through all the checks. That makes this code run much slower than a regex.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans although in this case it will **always** succeed within the first two checks. Any value other than "a" will evaluate true on the first, and "a" will evaluate true on the second: this statement will always evaluate as true.

Comment: @PeterRader there's no such thing as `!===` :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One nice way to do this is to put all vowels in a string and use `indexOf`:

```js
if ("aeiou".indexOf(myArray[i]) === -1) {
    // Do a thing if myArray[i] is not a vowel
}
```

If you need case insensitivity, use `myArray[i].toLowerCase()`.

---

As mentioned by Mike 'Pomax' Kamermans in a comment for this answer, it's better and faster to use regex to check the entire string for vowels instead of checking each individual character. That solution would look something like:

```
if (!myString.match(/[aeiou]/) {
    // Do a thing if myString doesn't have any vowels
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this, I knew there had to be a better way.

Comment: One thing to note is that although this is short and does work, it is not very intuitive: unless you know this trick, somebody else may have to take a moment to work out what you're trying to do. That's not usually desirable!

Comment: True, it does require a bit more thought, but it's certainly more readable than the OP's original code. IMO the tradeoff is worth it, but it's up to you to decide that.

Comment: That's what comments are for! Nothing wrong with using an unintuitive method if the code includes a simple comment stating what it's doing.

Comment: While it's certainly preference, at the very least it needs a clear explanation of what you're trying to do. If you're going to do this, comment it well! (edit: @IStanley got there before me)

Comment: @Chirpizard for learning purposes, a nice trick to know, but this is not a "better" way so much as "a way". A *better* way is (as you've already hinted) using a regex match: while this solution checks letter by letter, and is very slow, using `"your original string".match(/[aiueo]/)` checks the entire string in a single, fast pass.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans That's great to know. Thanks for sharing!

Comment: What if I wanted to modify this to check for any "falsy" values?

Answer (score 2):

try,

```
//the myArray[i] is not a vowel
if (["e","e","o","i","u"].indexOf(myArray[i]) === -1 ) {
    console.log(myArray[i] + "");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make an array of vowels and then search if your key is inside the array.

```js
var arrVowels = ['a','e','i','o','u'];
var myArray = ['b'];
if(!in_array(myArray[0], arrVowels)) {
    alert(" is not in the array! ");
}

function in_array(needle, haystack) {
  var key = '';
  for (key in haystack) {
    if (haystack[key] == needle) {
      return true;
    }
  }

  return false;
}
```

### EDIT

To all critic people, see more about `in_array()` function:

http://phpjs.org/functions/in_array/

Comment: I think `.indexOf()` would be a little easier. Also, it's not good practice to use `for ... in` on JavaScript arrays.

Comment: Report it to phpjs.org. Tons of expert people use `for..in` in certain situations. That situation is not dangerous.

Comment: You're over-complicating this answer by introducing a strict comparison - the OP is comparing to simple strings

Comment: @JonStory that's a correct code. Maybe `indexOf` is simplest, but this function is reusable in anywhere.

Comment: phpjs is a blight on the world of web programming. And the point of avoiding `for ... in` on arrays is that you don't know whether it's dangerous or not.

Comment: I'm not saying to use indexOf (which is not intuitive), I'm saying you're giving an option of a strict `===` comparison or `==`, when you don't need to and that over-complicates the function. You could just use ONE of `===` or `==` without the strict parameter and have a simpler function with higher performance. I know what you mean that this function can be used for any haystack/needle, but for the original question it's over-complicated code. At the very least you should use `argstrict = true` or `argstrict = false` to make the parameter optional.

Comment: I love strict mode, but maybe you have a piece of truth. Overcomplicated I don't know, in my opinion is a full-feature function. It's not mine, it's from phpjs.org library that includes a lot of useful functions in javascript copied from php. I will edit the answer without the parameter and all happy :)